# Error permission denied (publickey) on GitHub

Tags: github, ssh

I'm having an issue with connecting via ssh git@github.com. [This article](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) was not any help, unfortunately. I was trying to install something with composer for a project, using a github library and it was giving me the same error.

When I just run the `ssh` command, I get the same error: `Permission denied. (publickey)`.

The output from `ssh -vT git@github.com` is as follows:

```
ericmbp:app me$ ssh -vT git@192.30.252.131
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.30.252.131 [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
The authenticity of host '192.30.252.131 (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.30.252.131' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/keyname-erickeyte.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/anotherkeyname-eric.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ekeyte/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

All I can think of is that I added some keys via `ssh-add` for another project, but what I don't understand is that it looks like it's attempting to apply keys even though they aren't necessary, right? Why would this be failing?

I don't have anything for github in my `~/.ssh/config file.`

Comment: Could you edit your question to identify the specific key that's supposed to work for github, and describe in detail how you set it up both in github and on your pc?

Comment: I always found this article helpful: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ Follow all the steps and it should work fine

Comment: @Kenster, I believe the 'git' user at github.com/org doesn't take a key at all... is this belief where I'm going wrong? :(

Comment: @EricKeyte Yes, github requires an ssh key to connect through ssh. Is that your problem? You never set up an ssh key for github?

Comment: @Kenster You are right, but I accidentally wrote "bitbucket.org" into my composer repositories fields, not "github.com". It's working now. :( Thanks for your help, I'm upvoting you.